# NullPointerException binding a Label's text to a TableView's selectedItemProperty

Tags: nullpointerexception, javafx-8, property-binding

I'm curious if there is a way to bind a JavaFX Label's `textProperty()` to a TableViews's `selectedItemProperty()` without getting a `NullPointerException` when no entry is selected, which is for example during initialization.

Here is a little snippet to illustrate the actual situation:

```
@FXML
private Label l_name;
@FXML
TableView<TableEntry> tv_table;

l_name.textProperty().bind(tv_table.selectedItemProperty().get().getName());
```

The `get()` can only return an object of type `TableEntry` when an item is selected, which is not the case during execution of the `initialize()` method in my controller class. So the code throws a `NullPointerException` trying to execute `getName()` on the actual "tablerow".

What is the best solution for this problem? At the moment I've implemented a `ChangeListener` on the `selectedItemProperty()`, which than changes the labels text by calling `setText()` directly. But this feels a little bit more complicated then it should be.

Comment: A `ChangeListener` is probably the easiest way to go. You can use a select: `l_name.textProperty().bind(Bindings.selectString(tv_table.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty(), "name");`. This will generate warning messages when the  selected item is null, but will still work. Otherwise, you can use a third party binding library ([ReactFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/ReactFX) has this [functionality](http://www.reactfx.org/javadoc/2.0-M5/org/reactfx/value/Val.html#selectVar-javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue-java.util.function.Function-), for example).